# How to open password protected Excel using Excel db connection string in VBScript

Tags: excel, database-connection

I need to connect password protected Excel and read data by considering Excel as DB. I use below DB connection string for connection. My problem is if the Excel is password protected, then how do I pass my password via DB connection string?

Without password protected Excel the below database connection string works fine. How can I do this with password protected Excel.

Connection string:

```
With dbConnectiion
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .connectionString = "Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;"
    .ConnectionTimeout = 40
    .Open
End With
```

Comment: Were you trying to connect data from one excel workbook to another, or from another application to an excel workbook which was password protected? If latter what is the application?

Answer (score 0):

Data in an Excel workbook that has been protected with a password can only be accessed by opening Excel and providing the password. The Excel desktop application handles the security and encryption involved in password protecting and is required to unlock the workbook. This is a good thing. It helps protect the data in the workbook.

It seems that trying to create solutions that pull password protected data are working against the initial intention of the password protection.

Comment: like normal database that also has password protection for security concerns and thats why while accessing the DB, we provide password in the connection string. The same way i want to do for excel. Why do u think it is against the initial intention of password protection?

Comment: Excel is not a data base and its security mechanisms are different.